# Is ever answering "No Basis for Judgement" on a reference request a red-flag

Tags: united-states, recommendation-letter

I am filling out a reference form for a student I supervised on a medium sized project who is applying for graduate studies.
The student is great, of all that I have supervised in this way they are significantly the best on a number of metrics.
They are also the only student who has ever applied for graduate studies.

It has a bunch of questions where i am ask to rate them on there e.g. analytical ability.

One of the questions on the form is:
*"Rank relative to others you have recommended for PhD studies"*
with options like To 1%, top 10% etc.
The last option is *"No Basis for Judgement"*.

Since they are the only person I have recommended for a PhD program, that seems like the correct answer.
Since I don't have anyone else to compare them to who I have recommended.

But I am wondering if I am I am interpretting it too literally.
and I should actually be answering this question with my total assessment of them (though there is another field for that); or with comparison to people who could have but didn't ask me for a reference; or to the set of people i expect would exist.

Especially I worry that saying *"No Basis For Judgement"* might be taken as a red-flag by the program administrator.

Comment: "the set of people i expect would exist"  That's the answer.

Comment: It is a full top 1%, if you want. This is overthinking at its summit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is common enough that it won't raise any flags. But if you have a chance to explain why then it would be better.

Of course, logically, for this particular question, because of the specific wording, *Top 1%* is actually accurate. But it is a bit misleading.

I think either is honest and that an explanation is warranted if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you can supply context either as comments on the form or as a separate letter.  This is where you can explain you “no basis for judgement”.  It is not uncommon (although maybe so for this specific question): you may simply not have the historical pool of students to make an informed comparison.

You can use comments or a letter to simply restate what you just included in your post, and this should be enough to justify an honest opinion AND provide useful additional information for a committee.